# Horrible, ugly blur when animating CSS scale in Firefox 48

Tags: css, firefox, animation

I'm not having this problem when setting the scale property alone on a CSS element, only when using an animation. Also, it doesn't happen in general. It only seems to happen on my modals.

This is what it looks like when I take a screenshot during the animation:

[image]

Yuck!

If I haphazard a guess, I would say this is some performance saving measure they've taken, but I'm not sure what's triggering it specifically on my modals and how to get around it.

This is roughly what I'm doing with the modal code: https://jsfiddle.net/q85h0esy/

```js
document.getElementById('animateButton').onclick = function() {
 document.getElementById('fadeMe').className = "";
 document.getElementById('scaleMe').className = "";
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('fadeMe').className = "fade";
    document.getElementById('scaleMe').className = "scale";
  }, 1);
};
```

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes scaleIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.fade {
  animation: fadeIn 0.3s linear 0s 1;
}

.scale {
  animation: scaleIn 0.3s linear 0s 1;
}

#fadeMe {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

#scaleMe {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 2em;
}

#scaleMe .sr-only {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  width: 1px;
}

#animateButton {
  position: fixed;
  top: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fadeMe">
  <div id="scaleMe">
    Lorem ipsum dolor
    <div class="sr-only">Screen reader content.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="animateButton">Click for Animation</button>
```

EDIT: Demo updated to show the problem.

In this example, the box content turns white and there is a gradient along the edges. This is because of the way I was handling screen reader only content, with a negative text indent.

Apparently Firefox treats that as part of the width of the animation and barfs out with the extra 9999px added to the left.

Comment: So, eeeh...is it possible for you to provide a code example that actually exhibits the blurriness problem? Otherwise, most of us would just be reduced to shooting in that dark.

Comment: I've been trying to do just that but I'm not having any luck. The source CSS is thousands of lines long so it's difficult to pick out exactly what's affecting it. I'm asking this question generally for people who have run into this problem before.

Comment: The problem goes away when I remove the font-awesome stylesheet. (using that for the close icon in the modal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by adding overflow:hidden on my screen reader content, however I suspect this visual bug can occur in other places, such as when animating very large DOM elements.

```js
document.getElementById('animateButton').onclick = function() {
 document.getElementById('fadeMe').className = "";
 document.getElementById('scaleMe').className = "";
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('fadeMe').className = "fade";
    document.getElementById('scaleMe').className = "scale";
  }, 1);
};
```

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes scaleIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.fade {
  animation: fadeIn 0.3s linear 0s 1;
}

.scale {
  animation: scaleIn 0.3s linear 0s 1;
}

#fadeMe {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

#scaleMe {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 2em;
}

#scaleMe .sr-only {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  width: 1px;
}

#animateButton {
  position: fixed;
  top: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fadeMe">
  <div id="scaleMe">
    Lorem ipsum dolor
    <div class="sr-only">Screen reader content.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="animateButton">Click for Animation</button>
```